# What does "shooting for the ministry" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

This is quoted from the novel *White Single Woman*.

> “So I’m a fucking sinner! Who are you, Mother Teresa? Isn’t a human
>   being allowed one mistake? For God’s sakes, are you shooting for the
>   ministry? I need you, Allie!”

I looked up "Shoot for". It means "To strive for something; to aspire to some goal. "

But I can't understand "shooting for the ministry". I think "ministry" means the department of one sector. Such as Ministry of Agriculture, Ministry of Foreign Affairs ...

Comment: Yes, **shooting for** = aiming for, that is, setting as your goal, here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The speaker is implying that Allie is being excessively morally zealous about something the speaker has done, and sarcastically suggests that she aspires to become a nun or minister of religion.

> **ministry** (*noun*) The work or vocation of a minister of religion.
>   ‘he is training for the ministry’
>
> [Ministry (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ministry)